# How to write ANDNOT in KQL query?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, kql, kql-query, keyword-query-language

I need to achieve a query where RefinableDate00 must be earlier than today

`RefinableDate00:1900-01-01..{Today}`

but also should not be null since if it is null, the result I want does not appear in the search.
RefinableDate00 has mapped property that is a custom column and the column doesn't exists in some lists so the value return null
I believe ANDNOT operator is what I need or it would be good if we can create something like if condition

```
(contentclass:STS_List OR contentclass:STS_List_DocumentLibrary OR contentclass:STS_List_PictureLibrary) {SearchBoxQuery} AND (-RefinableDate00:1900-01-01..{Today}) AND (RefinableString00=True)
```

I expect results earlier than today, and results that RefinableDate00 might be equal

Comment: it would be helpful if you provide a sample input table using the `datatable` operator and the expected output.

Comment: I am pretty noob here, but I added my query, I only want results earlier than today but since not all lists have that date field, items don't have that column don't return

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mean this operator: <>

Comment: Isn't this not equal operator?

Comment: I think Yes. <> - Returns search results where the property value does not equal the value specified in the property restriction. https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/blob/master/docs/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference.md

Comment: Though it doesn't work if the value is null. I made a workaround like this:   ``-RefinableDate00:{Today}..3000-12-12``, this means if not in between today and 3000 so I can show null values and days before today. Still if you have better solutions I would like to hear cuz this looks brute force